# IE triggers scroll event more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events

This is an event handler:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e){
           e.stopPropagation();    
           e.preventDefault();
           if ((window.innerHeight + document.body.scrollTop) >= document.body.scrollHeight)
              if (window.location.hash=='#/')
                window.location.hash='#/1'; 
              else
                window.location.hash='#/';      
       });
```

I have the following problem: Everything is okay in Mozilla and Chrome, however IE changes `window.location.hash` **more than once** when scrolling is reaching the page bottom and that creates problems.*How may I prevent this change to be happened more than once when we scroll down to the bottom?*

Comment: `scroll` events fire rapidly, up to one per pixel of scrolling. look into debounce pattens

Comment: Could you declare a flag `atTheBottom` (in a closure) and set it to true when reaching the bottom and to false if not? You would process the hash only if the flag is not already set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (debounce patterns)